# Add a line to a list and canvas

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I'm currently trying to add a regular line shape to both the canvas and a custom object.  I'm not getting an error, but the line is not being added to the canvas

The relevant bit of code is below

```
lh = new LineHolder();
Line lnx = new Line();

lnx.StrokeThickness = 1;

MainCan.Children.Add(lnx);

lh.MainLiner = lnx;
lstLH.Add(lh);
```

lstLH is a list of LineHolder objects.

Has anyone ever encountered something like this before?  It does not like being added to both entities it seems.

Thanks
~Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried setting the X and Y coordinates, and got the same result.  I did put the coordinate matching in a second function (it does it twice) and call it with a timer  after the lines are added to the canvas, and that works for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

I it possible that you need to specify the Top and Left properties of the child your adding?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean by the Op?

Comment: sorry...I left out half of my sentence...try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think Micah is on the right track - except the most properties on the Line you need to set are X1, Y1, X2, Y2 - namely the coordinates of each end of the line.  If this doesn't work, I'd suggest setting the Fill property as well.

I don't think adding the line to your own object is the problem here.